# Submit load page inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I created this routine to do a submit and open a page inside a DIV. The javascript recognizes the DIV, but the page is opened overlaying the main page, outside the DIV. Does anyone know what the error could be?

Thanks

```
<head>
   <script>

      jQuery($ => {
      $('.e-chiedi').on('click', e => {
         let $btn = $(e.target);
         $.MessageBox({
                     buttonDone  : "Si",
                     buttonFail  : "No",
                     message     : "Mymessage"
                  }).done(function(){
                     document.getElementById("formHome").action = "inc_tessera.php#divTessera";
                     document.getElementById("formHome").submit();
                  }).fail(function(){
                     
                  });
      });
      });
</head>

<body>
   <div id="divTessera" style="display: none; ">divTessera</div>
   <input id="x" name="x" type="button" class="e-chiedi" data-message="test" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form (or follow a link) the result will be opened in a [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context). That can be a window, a tab, or a frame. It cannot be a div.

You can either:

- Replace the div with an iframe and use the `target` attribute on the form
- Not submit a form and, instead, use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make the HTTP request and [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to display the result in the div.